# Encrypt a word line by line

Tags: python

I have this script that opens a file and encrypts it to base64 and then saves the encryption in file `output.txt`, but there is a problem, it collects the words in a file in one line, I want to print each word in a file and save each word on a new line and not in one line.

For example:
Where is my problem in my code?

```
import base64

with open("out.txt","r") as file:
    count = 0

    while True: 
        count += 1

        # Get next line from file 
        line = file.read()

        # if line is empty 
        # end of file is reached 
        if not line: 
            break
        message_bytes = line.encode('ascii')
        base64_bytes = base64.b64encode(message_bytes)
        base64_message = base64_bytes.decode('ascii')
        print(base64_message.format(count, line.strip()), file=open("output.txt", "a"))
```

Comment: Worth noting that encoding and encryption are different. You're encoding here, which is writing something in a certain format. Encryption is about obscuring a message so it can only be read with a secret key.

Comment: `line = file.read())` reads the whole file and stores it in the variable `line` — so that actually contains all the **lines** in the file.

Answer (score 1):

You encode your file like this:

```
import base64

with open("input.txt","rb") as in_file:
    with open("output.txt", "wb") as out_file:
        for line in in_file:
            out_file.write(base64.b64encode(line) + b"\n")
```

You can open both input and output files with `"rb"` (read bytes) and `"wb"` (write bytes), so you don't have to do the ascii encoding yourself. With `for line in input` you go over each line of the input file one by one, so that you can encode them one at a time. The last important part is the `+ b"\n"` at the end, which adds a new line for every line of the input file.